# What is the meaning of "Dual Accuracy" on this datasheet?

Tags: experimental-physics, measurements, error-analysis, instrument

I'm trying to determine the uncertainty in some of my measurements, and one of the variables I measure is temperature, using a Tenma 72-7715 thermometer. I looked up the datasheet to find the measurement uncertainty of this instrument, and this is what I found:

[image]

What does the "dual accuracy" mean? My initial thoughts are that it means the thermometer is accurate to $\pm$ 0.2% of the measured value + 0.6 °C but that latter part seems like a very large error for this instrument.

Comment: Well, your intuition was correct - it is only good to 0.2%. Which is a couple of degrees C at the top of the K temperature range and more than good enough for most university measurements (and, frankly, real process control).